# SQL selection from one of four columns?

Tags: sql

I have a database table with four columns:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4
```

The value in each of those four columns will either be a price such as ($3.99) or will have the value 'Listed'.

I would like to know the best SQL query to find the following:

- Get all rows where all four rows equal 'Listed'
- Get all rows where some of the columns have prices and some have the value 'Listed'

Comment: Have you tried to create the query yourself?

Comment: Do them in the order listed.  The first one is easier.  Also, your options are determined by your database engine, which you failed to specify.

Comment: It may be a good idea to rethink your database design - this sounds like it should be two columns. In general, numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings. What database is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query !

**When all four rows equals to 'Listed' :**

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     [table name]
WHERE 
         Column1='Listed' 
AND 
         Column2='Listed' 
AND 
         Column3='Listed' 
AND 
         Column4='Listed'
```

**When some of the columns have prices and some have the value 'Listed' :**

```
    SELECT   * 
    FROM     [table name]
    WHERE 
         (
             Column1='Listed' 
    OR
             Column2='Listed' 
    OR
             Column3='Listed' 
    OR
             Column4='Listed'
         )
    AND 
         (
            Column1 LIKE '$%.%'
    OR 
            Column2 LIKE '$%.%'
    OR 
            Column3 LIKE '$%.%'
    OR       
            Column4 LIKE '$%.%'
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

These are actually fairly simple queries

Select where all 4 columns are listed.

```
SELECT * FROM {table}
WHERE Column1='Listed' AND Column2='Listed' AND Column3='Listed' AND Column4='Listed'
```

Select where at least one column is listed and at least one column is a price(numeric)

```
SELECT * FROM {table}
WHERE (Column1='Listed' OR Column2='Listed' OR Column3='Listed' OR Column4='Listed')
AND (ISNUMERIC(Column1) OR ISNUMERIC(Column2) OR ISNUMERIC(Column3) OR ISNUMERIC(Column4))
```

Something like these should give you what you want, no guarantees though since different database engines use some slightly different SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `testing` WHERE Col1='Listed' AND Col2='Listed' AND Col3='Listed' AND Col4='Listed'
```

And for the "OR" statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `testing` WHERE Col1='Listed' OR Col2='Listed' OR Col3='Listed' OR Col4='Listed'
```

Of cours you'll need to replace Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4 with your Column names. Also change your table name.